# print() function's end argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have:

```
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('x')
```

it will print ‘x’ every second, 10 times, each on its own line.

However, if I change it to be `print('x', end='')` to make the ‘x’ print all on the same line, the script appears to do nothing for 10 seconds and then dumps all 10 x’s at once.

Why?

Comment: Not sure why this would be marked as a duplicate considering the three links provided as "already have an answer" have absolutely nothing to do with my question. Oh well.

Comment: Chris: It's because of the buffering of stdout.

Comment: Thanks, wim already answered this though!

Comment: @vaultah I think we could add more duplicate targets...

Comment: your last original question is the best so far.

Comment: The last two are good (though the second last one I would have never found because I had no idea what "flush" meant prior to asking this question). The first three aren't helpful at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Line buffering**.  It's waiting for a new line character before flushing stdout.

Try this instead:

```
print('x', end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: Why should that be a thing now with print as a function? The intention is clear, no? I'm not saying this is wrong btw

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you! Marked your answer as correct.